# React application build on jenkins

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jenkins, npm, jenkins-groovy

How do I build a React application in Jenkins? I'm trying to use the npm run build command, but I'm getting errors on Jenkins. Can anyone help me with this?

I'm facing the below error

```
> react-scripts build

sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! maintenance_web@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the maintenance_web@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-08-02T18_36_55_475Z-debug.log
Post stage
```

Comment: How is your pipeline script? Based on `npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?` error message you do not run `npm ci` or `npm install` command before trying to build the app.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: how you execute this command? and where? is it Jenkinsfile/freestyle with K8s plugin or docker or executed on jenkins itself?

Answer (score 0):

could be missed `react-scripts` so you need to install it

`npm i react-scripts`

and double check that you executed `npm install` before!!!